# How to schedule Visa interview to some consulate other than post of interview?

Tags: visas, f1-visas

I am from India and will be applying for the F1 US Visa. For scheduling the interview and biometrics, I need to select my residence state, which will choose my post of the interview by default.

In my DS160, I have selected the embassy, that is not the post of the interview.

Do this post of the interview be changed to any consulate (within the country)? What exactly the post of interview means?

Comment: Note that at the moment all US posts in India are either temporarily closed or only accepting emergency applications. See https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html for details and https://www.usembassy.gov/india/ for a list of posts in India.